# While installing Epiphany-extensions, find error at make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: make

How to deal with the error of command "make".
Just like this.

```
oak@oak-HP-Z210-Workstation:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for oak: 
Hit:1 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:4 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Fetched 328 kB in 1s (564 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
oak@oak-HP-Z210-Workstation:~$ wget https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/gnome/sources/epiphany-extensions/1.8/epiphany-extensions-1.8.0.tar.bz2
--2021-05-31 14:43:10--  https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/gnome/sources/epiphany-extensions/1.8/epiphany-extensions-1.8.0.tar.bz2
Resolving mirrors.ustc.edu.cn (mirrors.ustc.edu.cn)... 202.141.160.110, 2001:da8:d800:95::110
Connecting to mirrors.ustc.edu.cn (mirrors.ustc.edu.cn)|202.141.160.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 611494 (597K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'epiphany-extensions-1.8.0.tar.bz2'

epiphany-extensions 100%[===================>] 597.16K  --.-KB/s    in 0.07s   

2021-05-31 14:43:10 (8.20 MB/s) - 'epiphany-extensions-1.8.0.tar.bz2' saved [611494/611494]

oak@oak-HP-Z210-Workstation:~$ sudo tar -xjvf epiphany-extensions-1.8.0.tar.bz2
I deleted the following lines.
oak@oak-HP-Z210-Workstation:~$ cd epiphany-extensions-1.8.0
oak@oak-HP-Z210-Workstation:~/epiphany-extensions-1.8.0$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for intltool >= 0.29... 0.34.1 found
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for iconv... /usr/bin/iconv
checking for msgfmt... msgfmt
checking for msgmerge... msgmerge
checking for xgettext... xgettext
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc static flag  works... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for glib-genmarshal... no
checking whether gcc understands -Wno-sign-compare... yes
checking what warning flags to pass to the C compiler... -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wno-sign-compare
checking what language compliance flags to pass to the C compiler... 
checking what warning flags to pass to the C++ compiler... -Wall -Wno-unused
checking what language compliance flags to pass to the C++ compiler... 
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for ngettext in libc... yes
checking for dgettext in libc... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for EPIPHANY_DEPENDENCY... configure: error: Package requirements (      libxml-2.0 >= 2.6.0         libglade-2.0        glib-2.0 >= 2.8.0       gmodule-2.0         gtk+-2.0 >= 2.8.0           epiphany-1.8 >= 1.8.0) were not met.
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively you may set the EPIPHANY_DEPENDENCY_CFLAGS and EPIPHANY_DEPENDENCY_LIBS environment variables
to avoid the need to call pkg-config.  See the pkg-config man page for
more details.
oak@oak-HP-Z210-Workstation:~/epiphany-extensions-1.8.0$ make
**make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.**
oak@oak-HP-Z210-Workstation:~/epiphany-extensions-1.8.0$
```

Comment: Why do you really think you need the software from 2005 year? The last available version for this package was [from 2012 year](https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/gnome/sources/epiphany-extensions/1.8). What is your final idea?  Which extension you miss in [deb-packaged epiphany](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/epiphany-browser)?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I just installed epiphany browser in Synaptic. I think epiphany browser is slim and fast than Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
checking for EPIPHANY_DEPENDENCY... configure: error: Package requirements ( libxml-2.0 >= 2.6.0 libglade-2.0 glib-2.0 >= 2.8.0 gmodule-2.0 gtk+-2.0 >= 2.8.0 epiphany-1.8 >= 1.8.0) were not met.
```

It means that you have to deal with these requisite packages first.

```
libxml-2.0 libglade-2.0 glib-2.0 gmodule-2.0 gtk+-2.0 epiphany-1.8
```

Then do `./configure` again.